# Apply filter to result of Django custom template tag (like i18n trans)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-i18n

We have a Django project with a legacy translation module that stores translations in the database, and does not use Django i18n (gettext).

We have written custom template tags `{% db_trans ... %}` that work like Django's default `{% trans ... %}`, but there is one trick we cannot duplicate.

In this example, "tree" (English) translates to "boom" (Dutch).

In my Django template, if I use default i18n and write `{% trans "tree" %}` I will see the result `boom`. When I want to use this as a title, I use the `capfirst` filter like this `{% trans "tree"|capfirst %}`, and the result will be `Boom`. Note the capital B.

This seems to be a special trick. Our `db_trans` custom tag (based on `simple_tag`) capitalizes the input before translation. Since there is no translation in the database for `Tree`, `{% db_trans "tree"|capfirst %}` renders its default (untranslated) value, `Tree`.

- I now about `{% filter capfirst %}...{% endfilter %}` and will probably use it if we cannot find an easy solution.
- I have checked the Django source code and I saw that `{% trans ... %}` is not based on `simple_tag` and does quite a lot of text argument parsing.

My question: is there a package or snippet that allows a filter specified as shown above to be applied to the *result* of a custom tag?

Comment: Can you not create another simple_tag called `db_trans_capital` that calls the same translation function and then calls `.title()` on the result? That's probably what I would do. That, or change it to a filter, so you can chain it `{{ 'tree'|db_trans|capfirst }}`

Comment: That would do it.

Comment: @Brobin if you add this suggestion as an answer I can credit you for it :-)

Comment: Done! Hopefully you can make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your template tag a filter, then you can chain it with `capfirst` built-in filter

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def db_trans(word, request):
    return do_the_translation(word, request)
```

Then in the html it would look like this

```
{{ 'tree'|db_trans:request|capfirst }}
```